# TAG replacement C string

Tags: c, string

Hope you can give me some light on this:

Have this entry:

```
BODY
10
<><BODY garbage>body</BODY>
```

so I have to replace all tags in < > and make the output look like this:

```
<><10 garbage>body</10>
```

any ideias? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void){
    char tag[128];//enough?
    char tag_r[128];
    char text[1024] = "";//enough? or dynamic array like as vector
    int text_pos = 0;
    int ch;
    enum { OUT, IN };
    int status = OUT;

    scanf("%127s %127[^\n]%*c", tag, tag_r);
    while((ch = getchar())!=EOF){
        if(status == OUT){
            putchar(ch);
            if(ch == '<')
                status = IN;
        } else {//if(status == IN){
            if(ch == '>'){
                size_t len = strcspn(text, " \t\n");
                if(len && strncmp(text, tag, len)==0){//match start tag(insufficient rigor), ignore case?
                    printf("%s", tag_r);
                    printf("%s", text + len);
                } else if(text[0]=='/' && strcmp(text+1, tag)==0){//match end tag
                    printf("/%s", tag_r);
                } else {
                    printf("%s", text);
                }
                text[text_pos=0]=0;
                putchar(ch);
                status = OUT;
            } else {
                text[text_pos++] = ch;//check omitted
                text[text_pos] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(text_pos)//invalid syntax
        printf("%s", text);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @ WOw i have some dificult to find out what is happening here:  
    'len && strncmp(text, tag, len)==0'     
i am also interested in make this idea more general  thats why I want to understand it completely

Comment: how can adapt this code to multiple entries? Thanks

Comment: You need to do the matching test to each entry.

Comment: but the entries will all change will be 3 new strings for time.

Comment: [link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10657400/) here is another input example. 
I've been trying to sove this for multiple entries all day log and nothing :/
thanks for the help

Comment: @Franks Search this site if is the substitution of just a string rather than a replacement of the tag you will find some examples.